# scipy curve_fit gives wrong results for float32 input

Tags: floating-point, scipy, curve-fitting

In the very simple example below (fitting a straight line `y=ax+b` with known outcome `a=b=0), the SciPy curve_fit function yields a wrong result when the x-variable is supplied as float32-type:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

def func(x, a, b): return a*x + b

x = np.array([0,1])
y = np.array([0,0])
p0 = [0.1, 0.1]
p1 = opt.curve_fit(func,            x , y, p0=p0)
p2 = opt.curve_fit(func, np.float64(x), y, p0=p0)
p3 = opt.curve_fit(func, np.float32(x), y, p0=p0)

print '\n p1 = ',p1,'\n p2 = ',p2,'\n p3 = ',p3
```

which yields the output:

```
p1 =  (array([ 0.,  0.]), inf) 
p2 =  (array([ 0.,  0.]), inf) 
p3 =  (array([ 0.1,  0.1]), inf)
```

Why is that last result (obtained with float32-input) different from the other two, and - obviously - wrong? Apparently, `curve_fit` has not performed even a single iteration, since the fit result p3 equals the initial guess p0. To me, this seems like a bug ...

Comment: If you encounter something that seems like a bug, report the bug to the developers of the software (http://scipy.org/BugReport).

Comment: its a problem with accuracy, espeacially for the jacobian estimation I think... the thresholds, steps, etc. are not automatically set to be reasonable for this case.

Comment: @all: I have just been informed that this is a known bug in `numpy.leastsq`, reported 4y ago (!)